# How to select only particular columns from navigation properties using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading, navigation-properties

I'm trying to select only 2 columns from the navigation properties but unable to do it, can anyone let me know how can I achieve this?

It works good default way(selecting all columns) :

```
  var productreceipts = db.productreceipts.Include(p => p.employee).Include(p => p.productmaster).Include(p => p.vendor);
```

What I want:

Select only 2 columns form each of employee, productmaster, vendor tables.

I know how to select if I have only one table:

```
var productreceipt = db.productreceipts.Select(p => new { p.ReceiptId, p.ReceivedBy });
```

**EDIT :**
I want to select all properties of first table(productreceipts) and only a few selected from others.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.Select(p => new { propertyName = p.productmaster.SomeProperty }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like :

```
  var productreceipts = db.productreceipts.Include(p => p.employee).
                                          .Select(p => new { propertyName = p.productmaster.SomeProperty })
```

Comment: I think, There is no need to use the `.Include()` function while executing query `.Include()` function is created for the some another specific/special reason. for more check out here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have lazy loading enabled then you can directly use

```
.Select(p => new { ProductId = p.productmaster.ProductId }
```

else you will have to take inner join and select individual columns in single select.

Comment: No lazy loading is involved here. This will work without lazy loading enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var productreceipt = db.productreceipts
    .Select(p => 
    new {   productreceipts_prop_1 = p.productreceipts_prop_1,
            productreceipts_prop_2 = p.productreceipts_prop_2,
            productreceipts_prop_3 = p.productreceipts_prop_3,
            productreceipts_prop_4 = p.productreceipts_prop_4,

            employee_prop_1 = p.employee.employee_prop_1,
            employee_prop_2 = p.employee.employee_prop_2,

            productmaster_prop_1 = p.productmaster.productmaster_prop_1,
            productmaster_prop_2 = p.productmaster.productmaster_prop_2,

            vendor_prop_1 = p.vendor.vendor_prop_1,
            vendor_prop_1 = p.vendor.vendor_prop_1,
    });
```

**EDIT:**

There is no need to use the `.Include()` You can directly use the navigator property to retrieve the data.

Comment: Cool this look good, but cant we shorten it, means why to select all properties manually for first table (productreceipts)

Comment: You can also do that, But you will receive the Object of the class `productreceipts`, In which all the properties are there.